# Mongodb aggregate $count

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I would like to count the number of documents returned by an aggregation.

I'm sure my initial aggregation works, because I use it later in my programm. To do so I created a pipeline variable (here called pipelineTest, ask me if you want to see it in detail, but it's quite long, that's why I don't give the lines here).

To count the number of documents returned, I push my pipeline with :
`{$count: "totalCount"}`

Now I would like to get (or log) `totalCount` value. What should I do ?

Here is the aggregation :

```
pipelineTest.push({$count: "totalCount"});
        cursorTest = collection.aggregate(pipelineTest, options)
        console.log(cursorTest.?)
```

Thanks for your help, I read lot and lot doc about aggregation and I still don't understand how to read the result of an aggregation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming you're using async/await syntax - you need to await on the result of the aggregation.
2. You can convert the cursor to an array, get the first element of that array and access totalCount.

```
     pipelineTest.push({$count: "totalCount"});   
     cursorTest = await collection.aggregate(pipelineTest, options).toArray();  
     console.log(cursorTest[0].totalCount);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Hmm, if I use await, it returns this error : 
```
 cursorTest = await collection.aggregate(pipelineTest, options).toArray();
                     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: If I don't use await, I got this error : 
```
(node:21748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalCount' of undefined
(node:21748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection
```

Comment: @Aux98 can you try this? collection.aggregate(pipelineTest, options).toArray().then(res => console.log(res[0])).catch(err => console.error(err))

Comment: Yes it is working like that, thanks for your help! Though, .toArray is really slow (takes 5 minutes to return a result). As I need to use this function 6 times it could be a problem. But I will try to optimize my code in order to reduce the time.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Aggregation**

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $count: "totalCount"
    }
])
```

**Result**

```
[ { totalCount: 3 } ]
```

**Your Particulars**

Try the following:

```
pipelineTest.push({$count: "totalCount"});
cursorTest = collection.aggregate(pipelineTest, options)
console.log(cursorTest.totalCount)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the console return : `undefined`

Comment: But indeed it's what I tried in first...

Comment: Ahh, you must be using a specific language - probably JavaScript...

Comment: Ho yes I forgot to tell that, indeed it's javascript.